# Python request's equivalent of curl's <<?

Tags: python, curl

I have an API that is showing me an example that uses

```
curl -X POST -d "@-" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://localhost.com/api/ <<EOF
{
    "origin_id": "test_user_id"
}
EOF
```

And I'm not sure how to do this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `man curl`:

```
If  you  start  the  data with the letter @, the rest should be a
file name to read the data from, or - if you want  curl  to  read
the  data from stdin.
```

The `<<EOF` is a bash way of saying "send everything after `EOF` to standard in". So another way to write this would be:

```sh
curl -X POST -d '{"origin_id": "test_user_id"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://localhost.com/api/
```

So in python this would be:

```py
import requests

requests.post('https://localhost.com/api/', data={"origin_id": "test_user_id"})
```